# Permanently change IP address on SuSE 10

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, sles

I am trying to change IP address of a SuSE 10 machine that is running Tomcat. I need to create a shell script to do this so could not use YaST.

As some sites suggested on my Google search, I edited the files in `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth-*` to change the IP address. After that, I restarted the network service by calling `/etc/init.d/network restart`.

The network card restarting just fine. I, then, restarted tomcat web service. However, when I browsed the new IP address using browser, I got an "Request denied" message.

Can anyone please tell me how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the IP in /etc/hosts? I think tomcat is trying to bind on the old address if you didn't changed /etc/hosts.

Comment: That is it. The `/etc/hosts` contains an entry that point to the old IP address. Change that to the new address and restart tomcat. It works. Thank you very much.